# Need assistance with T-SQL query

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have the following table...

```
orderID | itemID
---------------------
100          3425
100          3432
102          4443
102          8754
102          3425
103          6511
103          1176
103          3584
107          4967
109          0067
```

Now I want the queries for the following...

1. return the number of `itemID`s for each `orderID`, but only for those `OrderID`s with 3 or more orders per `orderID`
2. Using a single query, find all the `orderID`s that have `itemID 3425` and list all the `itemID`s for these `orderID`s.

For the first one I tried...

```
SELECT orderid,COUNT(itemid) AS item_count
FROM orderitems 
WHERE (select COUNT(orderid) from orderitems) >2
GROUP BY orderid.
```

But it's not giving the desired result....I am new to T-SQL please help...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Combined Query for 1 AND 2.

```
SELECT  OrderID
FROM    tableName
GROUP   BY OrderID
HAVING  COUNT(*) >= 3 AND
        SUM(CASE WHEN ItemID = 3425 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) >= 1
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/fb68e/1)

**UPDATE 1**

If those two problems are different,

For Problem 1

```
SELECT  OrderID
FROM    tableName
GROUP   BY OrderID
HAVING  COUNT(*) >= 3
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/fb68e/2)

For Problem 2

```
SELECT  a.*
FROM    tableName a
        INNER JOIN
        (
            SELECT  OrderID
            FROM    tableName
            GROUP   BY OrderID
            HAVING  SUM(CASE WHEN ItemID = 3425 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) >= 1
        ) b ON  a.OrderID = b.OrderID
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/fb68e/4)

Comment: it should return 103 as well